# Create a list in Python containing data from specified columns in a csvfile

Tags: python, list, pandas

I have a csvfile that I read in like so:

```
with io.open(script, 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as csvfile:
    entireFile = csv.reader(csvfile)
```

I want to loop through 'entireFile' and copy specific columns to a new list. I have another list, lets call it 'wantedColumnsList', that contains the names of the column headers that I want to copy over like so:

```
wantedColumnsList = ["Column2", "Column5", "Column9"]
```

So to reiterate, I want to loop through 'entireFile' and copy all the data into a new list, but only the data contained in the columns outlined in wantedColumnsList.
The reason I want to to do this (just to provide some context) is so that I can loop through the new list and search for any null values. If I find a null value, I want to be able to print out the column name that contains the null.
Essentially I'm creating a script that reads in a file and checks if certain columns contain null values when they shouldn't.
Thank you!

Comment: Have you heard of [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)? Are you opposed to using it? If not, this task becomes very simple.

Comment: I haven't used pandas before, how do I use it to solve this problem?

Comment: Well, Stack Overflow is not so much then "How do I do it?" site. It's more like "Thank you for the pointer, I will dive into it."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are open to `pandas` you can use this code to filter out desired columns:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig')
wantedColumnsList = ["Column2", "Column5", "Column9"]

df = df[wantedColumnsList]
```

And if you want to dump it to `csv` afterwards just use:

```
df.to_csv('your_new_file.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

**EDIT:**
And to find columns with `nan`:

```
df.columns[df.isnull().any()].tolist()
```

To find specific rows with `nan`:

```
df[df.isnull().any(axis=1)]
```

Comment: Thank you, this approach worked! Any ideas on how to search for Null values within the Data Frame?

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.split(splitting_symbol)` to split your csv to a 2D list and iterate it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a second list to check for nulls. Just iterate over a `csv.DictReader`, check the wanted fields for null values, and print the field names if null(s) are found.

```
import csv

wanted_fields = ("Column2", "Column5", "Column9")

with open('data.csv') as f:
    for line_no, row in enumerate(csv.DictReader(f), 2):
        null_fields = [field for field in wanted_fields if row[field] == '']
        if null_fields:
            print('Line {} contains null in column(s) {}'.format(line_no, ', '.join(null_fields)))
```

**Demo**

For sample data:

```
Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5,Column6,Column7,Column8,Column9,Column10
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
1,,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
1,,3,4,,6,7,8,9,10
1,,3,4,,6,7,8,,10
1,2,3,4,,6,7,8,9,10
,,,,,,,,,
```

Output

```
Line 3 contains null in column(s) Column2
Line 4 contains null in column(s) Column2, Column5
Line 5 contains null in column(s) Column2, Column5, Column9
Line 6 contains null in column(s) Column5
Line 7 contains null in column(s) Column2, Column5, Column9
```